# Variable for XPath nodes

Tags: xslt

I'm starting to learn XSLT/XPath, and I copied the following from a study guide, making some modifications:

```
    <xsl:variable name="fname"   select="'polist.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="thePath" select="'/collection/doc'"/>
    ...
    <xsl:value-of select="count(doc($fname)/collection/doc)"/>
```

It reports the number of doc elements in the XML file. The doc() function accepts the file name variable 'fname'. But if I try to do the same with the 'thePath' variable in the count() function, using $thePath instead of the "/collection/doc" text, I get an error.

Suggestions on whether/how to use the 'thePath' variable in the count() function? Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: In XSLT 3.0 you can use the `xsl:evaluate` instruction to convert a *string* to an *expression*: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dynamic-xpath

Comment: Which version of XSLT and/or XPath do you use? The use of the `doc` function suggests it should be XPath 2.0 or higher and there `count($thePath)` should work, counting the single string value the variable is bound to. i.e. giving the value `1`. So that is probably not the use case you have in mind. As others have commented or answer, XSLT 3 has `xsl:evaluate` to evaluate strings that represent XPath expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Learning from examples leaves you very exposed to this kind of problem: it's easy to build a completely incorrect mental model of how the examples actually work. That's why I always advise people to start by reading a good book that explains the concepts first.

In your case you've made a common mistake, which is to assume that variables work like macros, that is, that they represent fragments of XPath text that can be substituted into an expression. That's not the case: variables represent values, the result of evaluating an expression, and you can only use a variable in places where a literal value (like a number or string) could appear.

(I suspect it's the use of the `$` sign that leads to this false impression. `$` is often used to represent variables in macro-like languages, for example shell scripts).

In XPath 1.0 there's no direct way of achieving what you are trying to do. In practice people either use vendor extensions for this, or they construct a pipeline in which phase 1 generates an XSLT stylesheet and phase 2 executes it (that's easier in XSLT than in most other languages, because XSLT is XML and can therefore be easily manipulated using XSLT).

In 3.0 you can evaluate XPath expressions supplied in the form of a string using the xsl:evaluate instruction. But very often, the requirement can be met better using functions. We don't know what the real underlying requirement is here so it's hard to know whether that's true in this case.

Answer (score 0):

An example use of `xsl:evaluate` in XSLT 3 would be e.g.

```
<xsl:evaluate xpath="'count(' || $thePath || ')'" context-item="doc($fname)"/>
```